# issues of reading csv files using read.table

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file, which has one single column

> id
>
> 66185
>
> 66186
>
> 66187

I read this csv file as follows:

```
 a=read.table("a.csv",sep=",",header=T)
```

But R gave the following error message

```
Warning message:    In read.table("a.csv", sep = ",", header = T) :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'a.csv'
```

Comment: Why not use  read.csv()  instead?

Comment: It is NOT an error... it is a warning.